# Console output not visible within Firebug 1.12.x on Firefox 29.0.x

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I use Firebug on my Firefox. And since a few days ago I have a little problem with the `console` object.

If Firebug is not opened when a page is loading, I can open Firebug and type for example `console.log('test')` in it. And I get the `test` output in the Firebug console as expected.

Though if Firebug is already opened when the page is loading and I type `console.log('test')` in it's command line, I get no output. But if I check the console of the built-in devtools, I see my output.

It looks like Firebug and Firefox are both using the `console` object and I got some kind of a conflict here. How can I tell Firefox to release once for all the `console` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebug/U5Lik1KetOc) with the combination of Firefox 29.0 + Firebug 1.12.x and some extensions. It's reported to Mozilla in [bug 1005859](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005859). The extensions known to cause this conflict are:

- Wappalyzer (reported in [issue 542](https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer/issues/542))
- Ghostery
- The easiest Xdebug
- Skype Click to Call
- Greasemonkey
- Nimbus Screen Capture
- 1Password
- Coupons at Checkout

Disabling these extensions fixes this problem.

Though the problem should just affect that combination of Firebug, Firefox and extensions. It should already be fixed within [Firebug 2.0](https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/2.0/) (requires at least [Firefox 30.0](http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/channel/)). So you should try out that version.

Comment: Nice to know. I'll wait for the releases. Is there any trick to restore de firebug console ?

Comment: I updated my answer with the extensions causing the conflict. The workaround for now is to disable them.

Comment: Thanks. I use some on theses extensions (Ghostery and Greasemonkey)